# im embedding a video and its not showing up correctly, html/css in ZOHO

Tags: html, css, zoho

https://encompasslife.zoholandingpage.com/Mark/

```
<iframe
  width="560"
  height="315"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsHa6-6pFYE"
  srcdoc="<style>*{padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden}html,body{height:100%}img,span{position:absolute;width:100%;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto}span{height:1.5em;text-align:center;font:48px/1.5 sans-serif;color:white;text-shadow:0 0 0.5em black}</style><a href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsHa6-6pFYE?autoplay=1><img src=/sackrace.jpg><span>▶</span></a>"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
```

Comment: Your website seems to be embedding videos just fine, if you mean the particular code you need to change the src to src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XsHa6-6pFYE"

Comment: dope yeah got it! thanks so much!!